# Scroll view for textview in android

Tags: android

I am adding three text views in a activity. I need scrollview for every textview. If i add scroll view the third one is only have the scroll view. How to set scroll view for all text views in a single screen(Activity)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can arrange this quite easily by adding a property `android:weight` to each of your scrollviews.

This does the trick :

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In auctor varius ligula quis imperdiet. Cras at arcu eget ligula lacinia aliquam. Donec ultricies neque eu nisl elementum sed luctus leo porta. Nunc gravida molestie sodales. Nam sit amet lacus a odio dictum dignissim. Pellentesque nec tincidunt urna. Praesent mattis dignissim ante, eu placerat leo placerat vel. Curabitur nec consequat nisl. Donec dapibus ante id enim faucibus ut scelerisque risus sollicitudin. Vestibulum ipsum sapien, molestie vel dignissim eleifend, ultricies vitae libero. Nullam sapien libero, posuere non ornare sed, tristique non nisi. Proin eu nunc sapien, vitae euismod neque. Fusce scelerisque purus sit amet leo accumsan scelerisque varius ligula interdum. Maecenas non mauris vitae lacus vehicula pulvinar sed quis dui. Nullam ultricies mollis tortor vel dictum. Phasellus tincidunt dui id odio sodales tincidunt. Curabitur malesuada dapibus neque, non malesuada augue tempus at. Integer et nulla et arcu sollicitudin semper. "></TextView>
</ScrollView>
<ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In auctor varius ligula quis imperdiet. Cras at arcu eget ligula lacinia aliquam. Donec ultricies neque eu nisl elementum sed luctus leo porta. Nunc gravida molestie sodales. Nam sit amet lacus a odio dictum dignissim. Pellentesque nec tincidunt urna. Praesent mattis dignissim ante, eu placerat leo placerat vel. Curabitur nec consequat nisl. Donec dapibus ante id enim faucibus ut scelerisque risus sollicitudin. Vestibulum ipsum sapien, molestie vel dignissim eleifend, ultricies vitae libero. Nullam sapien libero, posuere non ornare sed, tristique non nisi. Proin eu nunc sapien, vitae euismod neque. Fusce scelerisque purus sit amet leo accumsan scelerisque varius ligula interdum. Maecenas non mauris vitae lacus vehicula pulvinar sed quis dui. Nullam ultricies mollis tortor vel dictum. Phasellus tincidunt dui id odio sodales tincidunt. Curabitur malesuada dapibus neque, non malesuada augue tempus at. Integer et nulla et arcu sollicitudin semper. "></TextView>
</ScrollView>
<ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView03" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In auctor varius ligula quis imperdiet. Cras at arcu eget ligula lacinia aliquam. Donec ultricies neque eu nisl elementum sed luctus leo porta. Nunc gravida molestie sodales. Nam sit amet lacus a odio dictum dignissim. Pellentesque nec tincidunt urna. Praesent mattis dignissim ante, eu placerat leo placerat vel. Curabitur nec consequat nisl. Donec dapibus ante id enim faucibus ut scelerisque risus sollicitudin. Vestibulum ipsum sapien, molestie vel dignissim eleifend, ultricies vitae libero. Nullam sapien libero, posuere non ornare sed, tristique non nisi. Proin eu nunc sapien, vitae euismod neque. Fusce scelerisque purus sit amet leo accumsan scelerisque varius ligula interdum. Maecenas non mauris vitae lacus vehicula pulvinar sed quis dui. Nullam ultricies mollis tortor vel dictum. Phasellus tincidunt dui id odio sodales tincidunt. Curabitur malesuada dapibus neque, non malesuada augue tempus at. Integer et nulla et arcu sollicitudin semper. "></TextView>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]