# how to put scrolled textview on secroll layout

Tags: android-layout, textview, android

i have to use  scrolled textview on scrolled layout so if i want to scroll the textview the whole layout scrolled when need just scrolled the textview and when scroll out text-view the whole layout scrolled  see the code t

```
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewOne"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="460dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="54dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="247dp"
                        android:layout_height="240dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:scaleType="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >
                    </LinearLayout>
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblTextViewBig"
                android:layout_width="229dp"
                android:layout_height="91dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@id/lblTextViewBig"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="@string/namm" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of items:
1) You have a dangling '>' near the end of your code.
2) If you want to just scroll the TextView, then only wrap the textview in the scrollview, see [Scroll view for textview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438857/scroll-view-for-textview-in-android) for an example.